# Getting rid of default values in spring rest

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

I'm using Spring rest with below code base:

When I invoke /info by passing string value in request body, I'm expecting the below response if this value is not present in my backend database.

```
{"output":-10}
```

but instead it returns me below response:

```
{"id": 0, "output":-10}
```

Can any one tell me how to get rid of this id default value? If there is a boolean variable in JSON mapper, then that would also get returned as

```
{"id": 0, "booleanVar": false, "output":-10}
```

Can any one tell me how to get rid of this default value?

Controller.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "heartbeat", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes="application/json")
public ResponseEntity<String> getHeartBeat() throws Exception {
    String curr_time = myService.getCurrentTime();      
    return MyServiceUtil.getResponse(curr_time, HttpStatus.OK);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "info", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json")
public ResponseEntity<String> getData(@RequestBody String body) throws Exception {
    ....
    myInfo = myService.getMyInfo(myServiceJson);
    return MyServiceUtil.getResponse(myInfo, responseHeader, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

MyService.java

```
@Override
public String getCurrentTime() throws Exception {
    String currentDateTime = null;
    MyServiceJson json = new MyServiceJson();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, false);

    try {           
        Date currDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        currentDateTime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").format(currDate);           
        json.setCurrentDateTime(currentDateTime);

        ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writerWithView(Views.HeartBeatAPI.class);
        return writer.writeValueAsString(json);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("Excpetion in getCurrentTime: ", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);           
    }
}

@Override
public String getMyInfo(MyServiceJson myServiceJson) throws Exception {             
    MyServiceJson json = new MyServiceJson();
    json.setFirstName("hhh");
    json.setLastName("abc");

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return mapper.writeValueAsString(json);
}
```

Views.java

```
public class Views {
    public static class HeartBeatAPI {  }
}
```

MyServiceJson.java

```
@JsonSerialize(include = Inclusion.NON_NULL)
public class MyServiceJson {
    private int id;
    private String firstName;   
    private String lastName;

    @JsonView(Views.HeartBeatAPI.class) 
    private String currentDateTime;

    // Getter/Setter for the above variables here
    .....

}
```

Comment: If you don't need `id`, just remove the getter & setter for it in your  MyServiceJson class

Comment: Removing id' setter getter will not work. User does not want to remove id attribute, he only wants to appear only when value set is not default one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Integer class instead of int primitive type. Primitive types always hold default values, where class type defaults to null.

Comment: I'm not clear. Are you suggesting to declare private Integer id; instead of private int id; ?????

Comment: @lokesh-Thanks...but there is absolutely no other way...I'm surprised! I'll need to define Integer for all my premitives, I have 4 int & 1 boolean, so I'll need to replace them with 4 Integer & 1 Boolean???? Are you sure this is how everyone is doing it??

Comment: I do not consider myself expert enough to comment if it is the only solution or there is any other. But, I have spent a lot of time solving this issue in one of my project and then I settled with this one.

Comment: Also, I have played with JAXB in my other projects too, and I do not know of a way to prevent it from using default value.